# Why in the completed event i get in label9 the value 1 when counting back?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

First in a backgroundworker completed event

```
int numberoffiles = 0;
        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                label7.Text = "Processing done";
                numberoffiles = ExtractImages.imagesUrls.Count();
                label9.Text = ExtractImages.imagesUrls.Count().ToString();
                newList.AddRange(ExtractImages.imagesUrls.OrderByDescending(s => s.Contains("region=is")));
                btnDownload.Enabled = true;
                progressBar2.Value = 0;
                CreateCountryDateTimeDirectories(newList);
                downloadFile(newList);
            }
        }
```

The variable numberoffiles value is 18 i used a breakpoint on the line:

```
numberoffiles = ExtractImages.imagesUrls.Count();
```

Then in webclient completed event:

```
long bytesFromCompletedFiles = 0;
        private async void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Download has been canceled.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.Error == null)
                {
                    ProgressBar1.Value = 100;
                    count++;
                    bytesFromCompletedFiles += totalBytes[count - 1];
                    label9.Text = numberoffiles--.ToString();
                    await DownloadFile();
                    if (progressBar2.Value == 100)
                    {
                        label7.Text = "Download completed";
                        btnDownload.Enabled = true;
                        Reset();
                        if (israelDownload == false)
                        {
                            string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(countriesMainPath + "\\" + currentDownloadCountry,
             "*infrared*.jpg");
                            sorted = list.Select(x => new {
                                Item = x,
                                Number = int.Parse(Regex.Match(x, "[0-9]+").Value)
                            })
               .OrderBy(x => x.Number).Select(x => x.Item).ToArray();
                            timer1.Enabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string error = e.UserState.ToString();
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
        }
```

imagesUrls is List contain 18 items.

I'm doing numberoffiles--.toString()
And i see in the end that i have 18 files on the hard disk.
But the value in numberoffiles in fact the value i see in label9 is 1
And i want it to be 0. Something is wrong with the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the assignment of numberoffiles--.toString() to label9.Text, the value is still 1. The value is decremented only after the assignment because you used postfix decrement operation.

[-- Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/wc3z3k8c.aspx)

> The decrement operator (--) decrements its operand by 1. The decrement operator can appear before or after its operand: --variable and variable--.
>
> The first form is a prefix decrement operation. The result of the operation is the value of the operand "after" it has been decremented.
>
> The second form is a postfix decrement operation. The result of the operation is the value of the operand "**before**" it has been decremented.

Postfix decrement operation (your case):

```
int counter = 1;
string text = counter--.ToString(); // text = 1
```

Prefix decrement operation (what you should have used):

```
int counter = 1;
string text = (--counter).ToString(); // text = 0
```

So in your case it should be:

```
label9.Text = (--numberoffiles).ToString();
```

Though, I would rather split decrement and assignment operations into separate lines for greater readability.

Added value: text is 0 for both prefix and postfix decrement:

```
int counter = 1;
counter--;
string text = counter.ToString(); // text = 0
```